# How to continue old conversation in Cortana after user clicks on a card that invokes a URL?

Tags: cortana, cortana-intelligence, cortana-skills-kit, cortana-invoke

As you can see from the below screenshot, we are able to create a Cortana channel based MS Chatbot that lists out certain information.

[image: Cortana MSBOT]

When we click on the card, we are getting navigated to the URL's as well but there are additional dialogues post this action. Cortana for some reason doesnt retain this information and we have to start all over again, as it loses its focus. Can someone suggest how to get Cortana to be at the same point where we invoked the URL click action?

Comment: I think this is more related to how things work on the Cortana side than botframework.

Comment: @ranusharao Okay. I accepted your recommendation but this was to get a better audience with respect to challenges people have deploying MS Botframework based chatbot with Cortana as a channel. Nevertheless, do you have some insights on this?